# Hide a relative div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am designing a contact form which has a 'Thank you' message pop up on send, I need my thank you message to be positioned relative, other wise if the user happens to scroll while the animation is running the message remains stuck in place and ruins the animation. However positing the div relative keeps it in the position before it loads, what I need is a way to have the div display:none or opacity:0 BEFORE the send button is pressed, is that possible?

Here is an http://jsfiddle.net/gcQ8f/ to explain what I'm trying to achieve a little better

And below is the Javascript I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".send-button").click(function(){

$("#contact-form") .delay(1000) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));

$("#contact-form") .delay(3000) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));
$(".contact").reset();
});
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign an ID or class (for example `id="myThankYouDIV"`) to your DIV and hide it with `display: none` in your CSS. Then when you're ready to show it (when you click the button), just call `$('#myThankYouDIV').show()` `$('#myThankYouDIV').fadeIn()`.

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question a bit. You want to show the "Thank you" message after the animation is complete, right? You still need to hide it using CSS, but to show it just do this:

```
$("#contact-form") .delay(3000) .animate(
    { height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' },
    400,
    function(){
        // animation is complete
        $('#myThankYouDIV').fadeIn();
    }
);
```

;

Comment: Hi @Gavin, thanks for your suggestion, that has however stopped the initial function entirely, here take a look http://jsfiddle.net/gcQ8f/6/ I  may well be doing something wrong as I am quite the novice when it cones to javascript

Comment: Well the 'Thank you' message is part of the animation, the effect I am after is quite simple, on clicking send I want the form to fade out (or slide) a Thank you message to fade/slide in, and the reverse it so the user ends up back with the form.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/gcQ8f/20/ There were quite a few errors in your code that I had to fix :)

Comment: Also, you are trying to reset your form using `$('.form').reset()`. This will not work in jQuery. You need to get the native javascript element like this: `$('.form')[0].reset()`

Comment: That is almost perfect @Gavin the only thing I want to do now is make the form fade out, is that possible? Thanks SO much!

Comment: Yeah, definitely possible. When do you want the form to fade out? After the animation is complete, or at the same time?

Comment: At the same time ideally, but Im tempted to change the concept of the animation and just have the form fade out to reveal a Thank you message, aesthetically for the end user it will work better. And thanks to your help I can do that! You're the man :)

Comment: To do that, you just need to add `$('.form').fadeOut();` Pretty easy :)